# Importing a page onto a differently sized page in Scribus

Tags: page-layout, typesetting, scribus

I'm quite sorry for my unclear question.

I have two Scribus documents, the contents of a club magazine (i.e. everything from TOC to colophon) and the cover (which is in color). For space reasons I would like to put the TOC and colophon on the inside of the cover, to minimize 'lost' space.

Scribus has a feature where I can import a page from one document into another, but the page sizes don't match up and I cannot move the imported page:

[image: Note top-right corner, I highlighted the layout-thingies. The imported page is clearly too much to the left and top.]
Note top-right corner, I highlighted the layout-thingies. The imported page is clearly too much to the left and top. Also, the elements from the master page are missing.

I would be very grateful for any comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but an idea of possible workaround:

Instead of importing the page you need I'd just copy its contents and paste into document with cover. To make placement easier I'd draw in source document a rectangle of page size and copy it along the rest of objects.

As a sidenote: why do you have different page sizes for cover and the contents?

Comment: Because for some reason the cover is done as a double-sided A4 and the contents are on A5. I quit the committee, though, so it's not my problem anymore :P Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No prob :). At least one problem less – good for you ;). BTW and AFAIK: Scribus can print spreads, so cover can be arranged as two A5 pages instead of one horizontal A4.